# How to change .index()'s default index of 0 to 1 for the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, position

I am using [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the position of the element. So by default it returns 0 for first one. Is there is a way to set default to 1 so the returned index would be 1,2,3... instead of 0,1,2...?

```
<div class="tabs">
    <a href="">1</a>
    <a href="">2</a>
    <a href="">3</a>
</div>
```

and the jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.tabs a').click(function(e){
        var index = $('.tabs a').index(this);
        console.log(index);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: don't add a hidden element to do this, you can use `data-id="1"` then read it using `var index = $(this).data('id')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change the default, but you could add it manually

```
var index = $('.tabs a').index(this) + 1;
```

If that's not good enough, you could create a plugin that would return the value you want.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myIndex = function(x) {
        return $(this).index(x) + 1;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

So you can then use `.myIndex` and get jQuery's index with 1 added to it.

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qGGku/)